# Is there a way to allow downloads or notifications in a chrome app?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, google-chrome-app, google-chrome-os

I am creating a chrome app similar to a web browser.  Currently it does not support download links or notifications from the browser.  It would also be nice to be able to add tabs to it.  I used the standard chrome app builder to create the basic app and then modified it in a few spots.  I will only include the changes to the codes and the line numbers because there are multiple files and thousands of lines of code.  If you want to see what I based the code off of, download the Chrome App Builder App from the Chromestore and create a test app and look through the code and folders.

background_main.js lines 15-21

```
   {
    id: 'KioskDesignerWindow',
    width: 1180,
    height: 1540,
    minWidth: 0,
    minHeight: 0
  },
```

cab.js lines 600-606

```
    },

{
  model_: 'BooleanProperty',
  name: 'enableNavBar',
  label: chrome.i18n.getMessage('app_config__enable_navigation_bar__label'),
  hidden: true,  // Taken out from v1.
  defaultValue: true
},
```

cab.js lines 2526-2531

```
properties: [
{
  model_: 'StringProperty',
  name: 'placeholder',
  defaultValue: 'Put the full URL here'
},
```

Comment: If you want to see the current version of my app, here is the link to download it.  http://squirrelboy2020.weebly.com/uploads/9/9/7/0/99707526/abse_0.4.zip

Comment: I promise it is safe, it is a .zip with a few folders.  Create one main folder and copy everything in the .zip into it.  To launch, go to chrome://extensions, click the developer mode check and click upload unpacked extension.  Select the entire folder and upload it.

Comment: See the [API list](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/api_index): notifications API is there. Nothing for the downloads though, so you'll have to implement the functionality yourself.